# How to display in the report last modification date of report design file?

Tags: birt

I am developing my report and I would like to trace what is the last version of the report deployed on the server.
I was thinking about checking last modification date of the report but still I have not idea how to do it in BIRT. Do you have any other ideas how to do that?

Comment: I am not sure I am following you. Where do you want this information and for what puropse?

Answer (score 0):

I do two things,

**First:**

Use  naming convention. All reports in the same family start with the family identifier in this case CoM (*Configuration Management, which is a module in the tool be reported on*) followed by a descriptive name of the report.

- CoM_ProductType.rptdesign

This is the name used for all production versions of the report.  Drop it in to where ever you store production versions (copy and replace) and existing links continue to function.

**Second**

Use a version Naming convention and track your changes and updates in the description attribute of the report.  This report has 3 version, Only the A3 version was promoted to production, the others were points during design and build.  I also track the report request number (C0000538688) and other significant changes.

- CoM_ProductType_A1.rptdesign
- CoM_ProductType_A2.rptdesign
- CoM_ProductType_A3.rptdesign

I save all the old version in an archive folder, that way when 2 weeks later the client decides they really did not want what they thought they wanted and start asking "can you change it back?" I just look through the notes in the description, go to the archive and pull up their last favorite version and redeploy it to production.

[image]

Comment: Hi James,
We deploy the reports on the server and we cannot keep easily naming conventions in our case.